# Why TeamCIty build fails with "because it is being used by another process", does it build parallel?

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a TeamCity installed on my server and my .Net Core project occasionally fails with the following message. If TeamCity uses parallel build, then how can I disable it? Or how can I make this TeamCity build more stable?

The code compiles on my dev machine without any issue, the code also compiles without any issue in Azure DevOps Build (a.k.a. Visual Studio Online).

```
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/home/tagent3/TeamCityBuildAgent/work/479321994f6f7261/.../Contracts.deps.json' because it is being used by another process.
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(FileMode mode, FileShare share)
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.ExecuteCore()
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
[22:06:31][build] /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)
[22:06:31]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an MSBuild switch `/m:1` (or `/maxcpucount:1`)
It says it should default to 1, but I have also seen comments on threads saying adding the flag fixed some parallel build issues so perhaps it has changed.

Docs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using argument verbosity normal level in **Command Line Parameters:** `-v n`

Comment: Can you explain how a build error can be fixed by setting another verbosity level?

Comment: I don't know the implementation inside these pipelines, but when I tried to understand what was going on using the verbosity it worked like a miracle, I remember that I removed these commands and the issue came back '-'

Comment: did you solve it with this ?? Can you explain? thanks